# Azure hosted website - FormsAuthentication not routing to defaultUrl

Tags: asp.net, azure, forms-authentication

I have the following setup in my `Web.Config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Landing/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Member/Dashboard.aspx">
      <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1"></credentials>
    </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

This correctly redirects when testing on locahost, but when published to Azure, logging in just redirects to `http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/` and not `http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Member/Dashboard.aspx` as described in the Web.Config. Interestingly enough, however, trying to navigate to a page without logging in correctly redirects to the defined `loginUrl="Landing/Login.aspx"`. Should I be using the FQDN in this case for the `defaultUrl`? Are forms authentication not setup on IIS of my Azure server? Please advise.

Comment: Do you see `ReturnUrl` in an url when user is redirected to login page? Something like https://yourpage.com/Landing/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f

Comment: @plentysmart yes, I see `http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Landing/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMember%2fDashboard.aspx` when trying to navigate to a page behind authentication.

Comment: `defaultUrl` is only used when there is no `ReturnUrl` that is why it works when you browse to this page without logging (`ReturnUrl` is the same as `defaultUrl`. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.defaulturl(v=vs.110).aspx): The DefaultUrl property is used by the RedirectFromLoginPage method if no return URL is included in the request. Similarly, the GetRedirectUrl **method will return the DefaultUrl if no return URL is included in the request**.
Not sure if it's your case, I'm just trying to eliminate the obvious.

Comment: @plentysmart I am currently using `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` to redirect upon authentication. Isn't that what is supposed to be used to redirect to the `defaultUrl`?

Comment: Have look at [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce(v=vs.110).aspx): 
The RedirectFromLoginPage method redirects to the URL specified in the query string using the ReturnURL variable name. For example, in the URL http://www.contoso.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=caller.aspx, the RedirectFromLoginPage method redirects tothe return URL caller.aspx. **If the ReturnURL variable does not exist, the RedirectFromLoginPage method redirects to the URL in the DefaultUrl property**.

Comment: "If the ReturnURL variable does not exist, the RedirectFromLoginPage method redirects to the URL in the DefaultUrl property" as such my problem is it not? I do not have a a `ReturnUrl` defined, so `RedirectFromloginPage` should redirect to the `defaultUrl` which it still isn't.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused, in your earlier comment you said:
"I see http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Landing/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMember%2fDashbo‌​ard.aspx " which means that `ReturnUrl` is defined so if you browse as not authenticated user to your main page you should be redirected to http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Landing/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f and this `ReturnUrl` will be used instead of `defaultUrl`. 

In short if there is `?ReturnUrl` in the url, it will take precedence over `defaultUrl` in web.config.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying now. So my issue is it looks like my `defaultUrl` is never used. So when logging in through `http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/` which has no `ReturnUrl` defined, I am not taken to `defaultUrl`.